# ZendServer ibm_db2.so stopped to load

Tags: php, zend-server, ibm-db2

I use Linux and I installed ZendServer for developement. I setted up everything and it worked until yesterday. Out of nothing I got this error and I can't fix it.

```
[12-Mar-2015 16:24:53 Africa/Blantyre] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/ibm_db2.so' - libdb2.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 in Unknown on line 0
```

In ZendServer > Configuration > PHP - I got warning that ibm_db2.so is not loaded.

I didn't update or upgrade for about 1 month (I'm not aware of some hidden updates). Everything was working ok before. Restart and reinstall of library didn't helped.